# Correct implementation of a step-size controller for embedded Runge-Kutta methods

Tags: c++, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I have been trying to write a code in C++ for embedded Runge-Kutta methods (explicit and Rosenbrock for the moment). The idea is to keep the code simple and general so that one can pass their Butcher tableau (of any order) and just run it.

I have verified that the code works in general, but there are cases (when I have a very complicated system of 4 differential equations) where the stepsize control fails to adapt (I get constant stepsize or just wrong in general).

The stepsize control I use (I found it in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S147466701751767X) is:

```
//beta is some safety parameter
fac=beta;


if(Delta<=1) {  //if current step is accepeted 
        if(delta_rej<=1){fac*=h/h_old; } //if previous step was rejected

        fac*=std::pow(Delta, -0.65/( (LD) method.p + 1.) );   
        fac*=std::pow( delta_acc/Delta, 0.3/ ( (LD) method.p + 1. ) );   
        h_stop=true ; //this is used exit a loop inside which the stepsize control is called

    }else{ //if current step is rejected
        fac*=std::pow( Delta , -1./((LD) method.p +1. ) );
    }
    
    //don't allow h to increase or decrease very much  
    if(fac> fac_max){fac = fac_max;}
    if(fac< fac_min){fac = fac_min;}
    
    //update h
    h=h*fac;
```

Here, `h_old` is the previously accepted stepsize, the step size of the current trial step is `h`.
Also, `Delta` [1] is the relative (local) error estimate for the current try (which the controller tries to make ~1), `delta_rej` is the Delta of the previous try, `delta_acc` is the Delta for the previous accepted step, and `method.p` is the order of the method (LD is a macro that can be double or long double).

I have tried using the simple version of this (i.e. just `fac*=std:: pow( Delta, -1./((LD) method.p +1. ) );`), but it seems that the previous one is a bit more stable.

For example, these are histograms I got that show the number of steps taken by my code vs scipy:
[Explicit RKF](https://github.com/dkaramit/NaBBODES/blob/master/.misc/RKF.jpg),
[Rosenbrock](https://github.com/dkaramit/NaBBODES/blob/master/.misc/Ros.jpg). As you can see, they are close, and the difference can be caused by the difference in the details of the implementation.

Having said that, I am still not sure, and what I really would like to know is whether I am using the controller correctly.

Thanks

[1]: [This is the definition of Delta](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?Delta%20%3D%5Csqrt%7B%20%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7BN_%7B%5Crm%20eqs%7D%7D%20%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7BN_%7B%5Crm%20eqs%7D%7D%20%5Cleft%28%20%5Cdfrac%7By_i%5E%7Bp%7D%20-%20y_i%5E%7Bp+1%7D%7D%7Babs%5C_tol%20+%20rel%5C_tol*max%28%7Cy_i%5E%7Bp%7D%20%7C%2C%20%7Cy_i%5E%7Bp+1%7D%7C%29%7D%20%5Cright%20%29%5E2%7D%20%5C%3B%2C%20%5C%5C%20N_%7B%5Crm%20eqs%7D%20%5Ctext%7B%20the%20number%20of%20equations%7D%2C%20%5C%3B%20y_i%5E%7Bp%2Cp+1%7D%20%5Ctext%7B%20the%20trial%20solution%20of%20the%20%7D%20i%5E%7B%5Crm%20th%7D%20%5Ctext%7B%20equation%20%7D%2C%20%5Ctext%7B%20and%20%7D%20abs%5C_tol%20%5C%3B%20%28rel%5C_tol%29%20%5Ctext%7B%20user%20specified%20tolerances%20%7D.)

Comment: I do not think there exists a definition of what "correct" means in this context. Of course ideally one would like a rapid, but "monotonous" convergence to the optimal step size for the current segment of the solution, but that is achieved by mostly all but the most primitive regulators. Some more recent discussion about possible misconception on how local behavior of the stepsize controller relates to global behavior and how to construct a "smooth" stepping algorithm can be found in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042705001123

Comment: In addition to what Lutz said, an easy way to check if you controller is doing something reasonable is to check that the global error is proportional to the tolerance, for tolerance to zero. (Given reasonably scaled initial timesteps and s controller based on local extrapolation and error per step control, which is rather standard)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I think the problem (at least in the problems I studied) is the global error, because the local error remains bellow the desired one... This is a strange behavior, and I am wondering if a midpoint method is somehow better than embedded ones (?).